PyQt5 - QtWebEngineWidgets error while trying to open a web page
For some reason, when i am trying to open a web page using QtWebEngineWidgets i show this error: [10316:10636:0407/073627.994:FATAL:tsf_text_store.cc(52)] Failed to initialize CategoryMgr.
MRE:
file: test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.deck_1_web = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.deck_1_web.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.deck_1_web.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.deck_1_web.setObjectName("deck_1_web")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.deck_1_web, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

file: app.py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from test import Ui_MainWindow
import pyuac
import traceback
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 0

# if i import the following two error oquered
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()
        
        self.web_page()
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def web_page(self):
        try:
            if "web" in dir(self):
                self.web.loadFinished.disconnect()
                del self.web
            #self.clearLayout(self.main_self.ui.horizontalLayout_9)
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
        self.ui.deck_1_web.show()
        self.web = QWebEngineView(self.ui.deck_1_web)
        print("1")
        self.web.setPage(WebEnginePage(self.web))
        print("2")

        #self.web.load(QUrl(self.tmp_item["url"]))
        self.web.load(QUrl('http://www.google.gr'))
        print("3")
        self.page_loaded = False
        self.web.show()
        print("4")
        self.ui.deck_1_web.hide()
        print("5")
        self.web.page().setAudioMuted(True)
        #self.web.loadFinished.connect(lambda ok: self.main_page_loaded_finished(ok))

class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        pass




if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = App()

Any thoughts? I am running python 3.12.x in windows 11 64 bit. the problem exist only with pycaw import or only with comtypes import.

That is not a MRE. Also, you said that the error is not there, but then you say that it is. Please make yourself clear and provide a proper MRE.

@musicamante i focus the problem creating a mre. The problem exists only with pycaw and comtypes` import. See question for mre.

If you're running this in the IDE, does the error occur also when running from terminal/prompt? And when does the error appear exactly?

It's also appeared from cmd. The error i think is confict between sys.coinit_flags = 0 , pycaw import and QWebEngine
